# UITableView Rounded Custom Cells (w/ image)

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitableview

I have quite a daunting challenge. I want to make this:
[image]

So:

- I use a table (plain not grouped cells).
- Cells must have rounded corners & shadow.
- I would prefer to use `CGRect` to draw the cells instead of using images (for speed & space economy).
- The cells in their most basic form look like **Cell 1**, but some have extra checkboxes like **Cell 2**.
- Tutorials that say to use images as background for rounded cells never touch on the point about **sliding the cell to reveal actions**. I think that by using an image the entire frame of the cell will slide and look really awkward. How can that be overcome?
- Is it possible to **mix cells**? Regarding adding checkboxes I though of 2 ways. Either **extend the entire cell** downwards and **add the checkboxes & text** OR just **add a 2nd cell type** specifically made for checkboxes (I prefer this option but I don't know if it's possible to mix cell types).

**NOTE: The cell is the ENTIRE rounded rectangle, not just the upper part (The upper part is the title). They grey line is only for style and will be just an image.**

I won't ask about a specific way of doing this. Each has it's own way of doing things. If you know how to do one of the things above (except creating a table view :) ), please help me (but keep in mind that it must be compatible with the rest)!

Note 2: Swift is preferred but Obj-C is fine too (unless code can't be ported to Swift).

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your effort to meet these requirements, then ask specific questions about the issues you are having

Comment: I can't even try because I don't know what to do. There is no tutorial about what I want to do. All other tutorials cover grouped cell tables. And even in those, none covers the slide to reveal actions. I just asked help about individual parts of this. I put effort in researching for hours and hours but I can't find anything.

Comment: I appreciate that you have done research, but there won't always be a tutorial or example covering exactly what you need to implement. That is when you need to TRY your best to meet the requirements, given what you already know. As written, your question is essentially asking someone to do your work for you.

Comment: As a start, try a custom cell with an inset view, adding the shadow and rounding to that embedded view. Likely the native swipe actions won't work the way you present, and you will need to implement them from scratch. The custom view might need to be inside a scrollview, that reveals the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would create custom table view cells for your table view by subclassing UITableViewCell, assigning it to your table view, and from there you would be able to customize the cell with a UIView and customize the .layer.cornerRadius including all the shadow properties on .layer